# How can I convert this SELECT to LINQ and use it in Index controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

can you please help me to write this SELECT to LINQ I need to use it in
Index actionresult

```
    select distinct programs_tests.testid , testname ,'' as 'Test count'
        from programs_tests
        inner join LabTests on programs_tests.testid = labtests.testid
        where labtests.TestId not in (51,52,54,55,56,57,60,1125,3161)  
        and programId = 1 
        and custid = 1 
        order by labtests.testname
```

I tried this code but alot of errors not used in LINQ :

```
 public ActionResult Statistics(int programId, int custId)
        {
           
            var stat = (from programs_tests in _context.programs_tests
                          join labTest in _context.LabTests on programs_tests.testid equals labTest.TestId
                          where labTest.TestId. not in (51,52,54,55,56,57,60,1125,3161)
                          select new ({}).Distinct();


        }
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Check out https://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: Use `new []{51,52,54,55,56,57,60,1125,3161}.Contains(labTest.TestId)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I will use it in where clause ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and this is the final code and how to use NOT IN in LINQ:

```
 public ActionResult Statistics(int programId )
        {
            int[] testids = { 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 60, 1125, 3161 };
            var stat = from programs_tests in _context.programs_tests
                       join labTest in _context.LabTests
                       on programs_tests.testid equals labTest.TestId
                       where programs_tests.program_id == programId
                       && !testids.Contains(labTest.TestId)
                       select programs_tests;
            return View(stat);


        }
```